# NaN or 500 error when referencing link within array

Tags: php

I'm using this array to show a random button on each page load.

```
<?php

/* 1. Create a static content array */
$day_array = array(

// Button 1
 '<button class="button" onclick=window.open('/path')>Button 1</button>',
 
// Button 2
 '<button class="button" onclick=window.open('/path')>Button 2</button>',
 
// Button 3
 '<button class="button" onclick=window.open('/path')>Button 3</button>',
 
// Button 4
 '<button class="button" onclick=window.open('/path')>Button 4</button>',
 
// Button 5
 '<button class="button" onclick=window.open('/path')>Button 5</button>',

);

/* Generate Random number */
$min = 1;
$max = count($day_array);
$random = mt_rand($min,$max);

/* And Save random number to a file */    
$file = fopen("./randomnumber.txt","a+");
fwrite($file,$random."\n");
fclose($file);

/* 3. Show randomly selected content */
// $random-1 because the array index starts from 0
// and we generated random starting from 1
echo $day_array[$random-1];

?>
```

I know I need to comment out the apostrophe but `'<button class="button" onclick=window.open(/'/path/')>Button 4</button>'` doesn't work for me. It works without but I need the buttons to have window open on click evens with `page01` etc. A URL is more slashes to comment out. How can use `window.open` without an error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to escape string you need to use the backward slashes, not the forward ones.

also, the value of onclick must be inside quotes.

your way

```
'<button class="button" onclick=window.open(/'/path/')>Button 4</button>'
```

correct way

```
'<button class="button" onclick="window.open(\'/path\')">Button 4</button>'
```